# .net XML Serialization - Storing Reference instead of Object Copy

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization

- In .Net/C# Application, I have data structures which have references to each other.
- When I serialize them, .Net Serializes all references with separate object copies.
- In Following Example, I am trying to serialize to Array of 'Person'
- A 'Person' may have reference to another person.

  ```
  public class Person
  {
      public string Name;
      public Person Friend;
  }

  Person p1 = new Person();
  p1.Name = "John";

  Person p2 = new Person();
  p2.Name = "Mike";

  p1.Friend = p2;

  Person[] group = new Person[] { p1, p2 };
  XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person[]));
  using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("test.xml"))
      ser.Serialize(tw,group );

  //above code generates following xml

  <ArrayOfPerson>
    <Person>
      <Name>John</Name>
      <Friend>
        <Name>Mike</Name>
      </Friend>
    </Person>
    <Person>
      <Name>Mike</Name>
    </Person>
  </ArrayOfPerson>
  ```
- **In above code, the same 'Mike' object are there on two places, since there are two references for the same object.**
- While deserializing, they become two different objects, which is not exact state when they are serialized.
- I want to avoid this and have only copy of object in serialized xml, and all references should refer to this copy. After deserialization , i want to get back, same old data structure.
- Is it Possible ?

Comment: Just found that BinaryFormatter and SoapFormatter preserves reference values.

Comment: SoapFormatter has been deprecated and it does not support generics.

Comment: While not an answer to your question, if not already obvious, a solution is to store indexes/identifiers instead of references and have dedicated logic before serialization for converting object references to indexes/identifiers and, conversely, after deserialization for converting indexes/identifiers to object references. You will mark references with non-serializable flag. If you have a simple structure with a few references, this avoids technical complications of the proposed answers and potential lower performance due to using 3'rd party libraries.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It is not possible with [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx). You could achieve this with [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) using the [PreserveObjectReferences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.preserveobjectreferences.aspx) property. You may take a look at this [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/sowmy/archive/2006/03/26/561188.aspx) which explains the details.

Here's a sample code:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name;
    public Person Friend;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Person p1 = new Person();
        p1.Name = "John";

        Person p2 = new Person();
        p2.Name = "Mike";
        p1.Friend = p2;
        Person[] group = new Person[] { p1, p2 };

        var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(group.GetType(), null, 
            0x7FFF /*maxItemsInObjectGraph*/, 
            false /*ignoreExtensionDataObject*/, 
            true /*preserveObjectReferences : this is where the magic happens */, 
            null /*dataContractSurrogate*/);
        serializer.WriteObject(Console.OpenStandardOutput(), group);
    }
}
```

This produces the following XML:

```
<ArrayOfPerson z:Id="1" z:Size="2" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ToDelete" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
    <Person z:Id="2">
        <Friend z:Id="3">
            <Friend i:nil="true"/>
            <Name z:Id="4">Mike</Name>
        </Friend>
        <Name z:Id="5">John</Name>
    </Person>
    <Person z:Ref="3" i:nil="true"/>
</ArrayOfPerson>
```

Now set `PreserveObjectReferences` to `false` in the constructor and you will get this:

```
<ArrayOfPerson xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ToDelete" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Person>
        <Friend>
            <Friend i:nil="true"/>
            <Name>Mike</Name>
        </Friend>
        <Name>John</Name>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <Friend i:nil="true"/>
        <Name>Mike</Name>
    </Person>
</ArrayOfPerson>
```

It is worth mentioning that the XML produced this way is not interoperable and can only be deserialized with a DataContractSerializer (same remark as with the [BinaryFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx)).

Answer (score 7):

You can use ExtendedXmlSerializer. Here is an example of serialization [object reference and circular reference](https://github.com/wojtpl2/ExtendedXmlSerializer#object-reference-and-circular-reference)

If you have a class:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Person Boss { get; set; }
}

public class Company
{
    public List<Person> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

then you create object with circular reference, like this:

```
var boss = new Person {Id = 1, Name = "John"};
boss.Boss = boss; //himself boss
var worker = new Person {Id = 2, Name = "Oliver"};
worker.Boss = boss;
var obj = new Company
{
    Employees = new List<Person>
    {
        worker,
        boss
    }
};
```

You must configure Person class as reference object:

```
var serializer = new ConfigurationContainer().ConfigureType<Person>()
                                             .EnableReferences(p => p.Id)
                                             .Create();
```

In the end you can serialize your object:

```
var xml = serializer.Serialize(obj);
```

Output xml will look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Company xmlns="clr-namespace:ExtendedXmlSerializer.Samples.ObjectReference;assembly=ExtendedXmlSerializer.Samples">
  <Employees>
    <Capacity>4</Capacity>
    <Person Id="2">
      <Name>Oliver</Name>
      <Boss Id="1">
        <Name>John</Name>
        <Boss xmlns:exs="https://extendedxmlserializer.github.io/v2" exs:entity="1" />
      </Boss>
    </Person>
    <Person xmlns:exs="https://extendedxmlserializer.github.io/v2" exs:entity="1" />
  </Employees>
</Company>
```

ExtendedXmlSerializer support .net 4.5 and .net Core.

Comment: you should mention that you are promoting your own software, that isn't part of the .net framework though does look like a good bit of work