# Specify how to Serialize my object if it is in a list

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization

I have a somewhat complicated Class that may or may not contain a list of items of the same type

```
Class Items
{
   List<Items> SubItems ...

}
```

The class itself is serializeable, however its going to be a giant waste of space to serialize the objects in the list  since they are  serialized and added to the database prior to being included in the list.

Is there a way that I can specify that the list should be represented as a list of integers when its serialized ?

Note: These integers will represent primary keys of the rows where the serialized object is located.

Comment: What kind of serialization are you using? XML, Json? Binary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way that I can specify that the list should be represented
>   as a list of integers when its serialized?

Yep. There are two main options:

**1)** Implement the [ISerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable.aspx)-Interface, where you can control how the object will be serialized / deserialized.

OR

**2)** Declare your List as [[NonSerialized]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nonserializedattribute.aspx) and also manage a private Member List, which contains your primary keys. You will have to implement the logic for loading / storing the Integer-List by your own, though.

If your class to serialize is quite big, I would recommend you the second approach, because in the other case you have to manually serialize / deserialize each property.

Answer (score 1):

To specify how an object is serialised, you need to implement ISerializable and provide an implementation for `GetObjectData`

```
public virtual void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) 
{

}
```

There is a simple example on this MSDN page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973893.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to save space, you can use `DataContractSerializer` to achieve that. It has preserveObjectReference option. Which doesn't duplicate same object instead only store referenceId.
Detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617528/net-xml-serialization-storing-reference-instead-of-object-copy)