# Serializing references to other serialized objects

Tags: c#, serialization, reference, deserialization, relationship

I have two serializable Classes:

```
[Serializable]
public class Word
{
    public List<string> similes;
}
```

.

```
[Serializable]
public class Lexicon
{
    public List<Word> words;
}
```

both classes are stored as XML files separately, however the XML files for Lexicon comes out like this:

```xml
<Word>
    <Similes>
        <string>Hello</string>
        <string>Hi</string>
    </Similes>
</Word>

<Word>
    <Similes>
        <string>Goodbye</string>
        <string>Bye</string>
    </Similes>
</Word>

<Lexicon>
    <Words>
        <Word>
            <Similes>
                <string>Hello</string>
                <string>Hi</string>
            </Similes>
        </Word>
        <Word>
            <Similes>
                <string>Goodbye</string>
                <string>Bye</string>
            </Similes>
        </Word>
    </Words>
</Lexicon>
```

And that's just with two words! You can see how this would quickly get out of hand  as more Words were added, additionally the "Hello, Hi" Word, when deserialized, is a different object to the one stored inside the deserialized Lexicon - when they should reference the same object.

So essentially **is there a way to make the serialized Lexicon file reference the files produced by serializing the Word instances instead of duplicating the xml?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.net XML Serialization - Storing Reference instead of Object Copy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617528/net-xml-serialization-storing-reference-instead-of-object-copy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a wordID to your serializable `Word` and reference this ID it in your Lexicon class

```
[Serializable]
public class Word
{
    public string WordID;
    public List<string> similes;
}
```

Your Word Class..

```xml
<Word>
    <WordID>1</WordID>
    <Similes>
        <string>Hello</string>
        <string>Hi</string>
    </Similes>
</Word>
```

Lexicon class

```
public class Lexicon
{
    public List<string> wordIDs;
}
```

Lexicon could be like

```xml
<Lexicon>
    <WordIDs>
        <string>1</string>
        <string>2</string>            
    </WordIDs>
</Lexicon>
```

Comment: That seems really obvious in hindsight. I feel quite stupid now, thanks!