# Understanding the concept of 'serializing by reference'

Tags: c#, serialization, protobuf-net, datacontractserializer

I'm writing my own binary serializer optimized for game development. So far it's fully functional. It emits IL to generate the [de]serialization methods given a sequence of types in advance. The only missing feature is serializing things by reference, everything is currently being serialized by value.

In order to implement it, I have to understand it first. This is what I'm finding to be a bit tricky. Let me show you what I understood in these couple of examples:

Example 1 (as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617528/net-xml-serialization-storing-reference-instead-of-object-copy)):

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name;
    public Person Friend;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Person p1 = new Person();
    p1.Name = "John";

    Person p2 = new Person();
    p2.Name = "Mike";

    p1.Friend = p2;

    Person[] group = new Person[] { p1, p2 };

    var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(group.GetType(), null, 
        0x7FFF /*maxItemsInObjectGraph*/, 
        false /*ignoreExtensionDataObject*/, 
        true /*preserveObjectReferences : this is where the magic happens */, 
        null /*dataContractSurrogate*/);

    serializer.WriteObject(Console.OpenStandardOutput(), group);
}
```

Now this is completely understood. We have a root object which is the array, referencing two unique persons. The `p1.Friend` happens to be the `p2`. So instead of serializing the `p1.Friend` by value we just store an id that points to `p2` which we've already serialized.

However; have a look at this second example:

```
    static void Example2()
    {
        var p1 = new Person() { Name = "Diablo" };
        var p2 = new Person() { Name = "Mephesto" };

        p1.Friend = p2;

        var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Person), null, 0x7FFF, false, true, null);

        serializer.WriteObject(Console.OpenStandardOutput(), p1);
        Console.WriteLine("\n");
        serializer.WriteObject(Console.OpenStandardOutput(), p2);
    }
```

Now, according to my understanding: when serializing `p1` the serializer will serialize `p1.Name` and `p1.Friend`. In the second `WriteObject`, the serializer has already serialized `p2` (which is `p1.Friend`) so it just serializes an id that points to `p1.Friend` instead of serializing it by value.

Running the code and viewing the output it doesn't seem to be the case. In the 2nd output we see the serializer serializing `p2` by value as if it hasn't came across it yet... And that I didn't get. It's like there's an id counter internally that gets reset at the end of `WriteObject`

[image]

Here's another similar example:

```
    static void Example3()
    {
        var p1 = new Person() { Name = "Diablo" };
        var p2 = p1;

        var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Person), null, 0x7FFF, false, true, null);

        serializer.WriteObject(Console.OpenStandardOutput(), p1);
        Console.WriteLine("\n");
        serializer.WriteObject(Console.OpenStandardOutput(), p2);
    }
```

Again, the second output shows that we're serializing `p2` as if we haven't encountered a definition for it yet.

Note that I didn't choose `DataContractSerializer` for any particular reason, any serializer that supports serializing by reference works.

I tried to ILSpy on `DataContractSerializer` but I got lost quickly and couldn't figure out much.

1. In `Example2`, why didn't the serializer store an id to
   `p1.Friend` when serializing `p2`? - Is 'serializing by reference'
   only applied to a single object hierarchy, or how does it work in
   general?
2. It seems to me that serializing by reference will automatically
   handle circular referencing (A <-> B), is that correct? or do I need
   to do other things to make sure I won't fall into an infinite loop?
3. I assume serializing by reference makes sense only when applied
   on reference-types and not value-types, correct?

I've tagged protobuf-net cause it's similar in that it's a binary serializer and emits IL. I would love to hear how seiralizing by reference is implemented there :p

Comment: Side note: you don't have to use ILSpy, you can look at the code here - http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Runtime.Serialization/System/Runtime/Serialization/DataContractSerializer.cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Each call to write-object is a separate serialization context; the reference-tracking is not preserved between calls
2. As long as you correctly identify previously seen values, it shouldn't get recursive, but a depth check can help avoid issues
3. Correct, although you *could* attempt to recognise semantically identical value types if you wanted (perhaps the structural equality interface)

Additional thought: if you apply this to strings, you might want to special-case as *effective equality* rather than reference equality - no point serialising two different instances (references) of the same string

Comment: Thanks for the reply. On 1- Is this a standard in all serializers that implement serialize by ref? or only in DataContractSerializer? does this mean there's no way in example 2 and 3 to serialize the second object by reference? or that doesn't make sense and it's a part of my misunderstanding?

Comment: @vexe this is pretty much standard in all serializers; you *might* be able to find one that has an API for preserving such, but that is **not** the expected scenario; it *expects* that each call to `Serialize` / `Write` / whatever is unrelated and separate. In particular, if you call `Write(obj, target1)` and `Write(obj, target2)`, it is normally expected that `target1` and `target2` will both have **identical** contents (or at least: equivalent contents). That cannot be the case if the second time it just says "I've seen these objects before: I'll just serialize the ids"

Comment: I was thinking about using protobuf-net and compile a dll for a type with fields marked with [AsReference] (if I remember correctly) and then view the generated code. It should have the 'serialize by reference' logic baked into the dll correct? so I can maybe get a general idea how to go about it

Comment: @vexe the logic for there is in the core lib, not the generated IL. There's *basically* a reference-keyed dictionary

Comment: Thank you. Lastly, do you recommend any reading/books that go in-depth into the subject? All the stuff I read teaches you how to use existing serializers and not how they work internally/how to implement one yourself.

Comment: @vexe I don't know of any such; you can read the source for XmlSerializer, Json.net, protobuf-net, Jil, etc - though!

Comment: So I've implemented it and it's working fine :) could you elaborate a bit on your last 'additional thought' idea? what do you mean with 'effective equality'? I assume you mean char-by-char equality? isn't the normal `==` on strings enough for that or do I need some special compare/equality class? cause I looked at your source and I saw you just newing up that strings dictionary with no arguments so the default equality stuff applies.

Comment: @vexe yeah, regular string equality is fine; the point I was trying to make was: don't use `object.ReferenceEquals` for strings