# Xml serialization with IDREF?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

Consider the `xml` below. In `C#` code, I'm using `System.Xml.Serialization` to serialize my classes. In my `Display` class I want to **reference** the `Category` object serialized below `Categories`. Note the use of `IDREF`.

How do I declare the class attributes to accomplish this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data>
    <categories>
        <category id="google">
            <name>Google</name>
        </category>
    <categories>
    <display>
        <categories>
            <category idref="google"/>
        </categories>
    </display>
</data>
```

And in `C#`:

```
// Display class...

[XmlArray(ElementName = "categories")] // IDREF?
[XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "category")] // IDREF?
public Category[] Categories
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617528/net-xml-serialization-storing-reference-instead-of-object-copy

Comment: Too bad :( But I suppose that I can easily convert my code to use DataContract instead...